# django - disable button in javascript based on text input

Tags: javascript, django

I've got problem to disable submit button conditionally. My js code is as follows:

```
function disableButton() {
        var btnSubmit = document.getElementById('sub_butt');
        if (document.getElementsByName('submitted').value == "yes") {
            btnSubmit.disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            btnSubmit.disabled = false;
        }
    }
```

In django I have updateForm with formset and I would like to disable button based on value text field with name "submitted". I've tried the code above but nothing's changed. Field "submitted" is already filled out with value 'yes'

Comment: How do you *trigger* the function?

Comment: I new is js. I don't have any trigger. How can I trigger it when: 1. page is loaded or 2. form is submitted?

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).  I'm guessing you have just *one* submit button and just *one* input with name of submitted for your formset?  If not you can still add an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to each text input using a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop, and trigger the disableButton function that way.